# CSS target element and include body class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target the .mylink class in this example...

```
<body class="body738">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="myholder">
            <div class="myitem">
                My Item Content
                <a class="mylink" href="#">My Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Obviously I can just target .mylink but I want to make sure that .mylink is within the body class of .body738

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you targeting it with?

Comment: It's wrapped inside your <body> tag not sure what you mean? please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the child selector.

```
.body738 .mylink { /* Rules here... */ }
```

This makes sure that it selects only elements under `.body738`, if not, it won't select.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to target `.mylink` within the body class of `.body738`:

```
body.body738 .mylink{
    /* Write your code here*/
}
```